# Azure Search - query ALL indexes in single search query

Tags: .net, azure-cognitive-search

In Azure search, if we have multiple indexes created, the search API seems to be directed to a given index only.

```
var searchClient = new SearchServiceClient(_config.ServiceName, new SearchCredentials(_config.ApiKey))
var indexClient = searchClient.Indexes.GetClient(indexName)
indexClient.Documents.Search(queryString)
```

Is there anything like

```
searchClient.Search(...)
```

which could search all my indexes in that search service?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately querying multiple indexes with one query is not supported. Please vote for this capability on our UserVoice page to help us prioritize future work: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/16700506-search-multiple-indexes-at-once

Comment: Thanks, i have added my votes to it. hopefully it gets implemented soon!

Comment: was this implemented, link is a 404 now? I would assume it isn't since I never found anything in the docs.